# Big simple keyboard for Android

Tags: gratis, android, virtual-keyboard

My grandmother recently got the LG G2, and her main complaint is that the keyboard buttons are too small.

She liked Fleksy, but we discovered that it was only a one month trial, and she doesn't want to spend four bucks on a keyboard.

Also, she didn't like the others I found on my own, as they had strange layouts.

This being said, is there a simple, large-button keyboard that is available for free?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [ThickButtons keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thickbuttons) which I have been using for years. Free tool, and it uses predictive text algorithm to enlarge the most-probable keys for the next character. Really good for my fat fingers and thumbs.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that she does not like strange layouts and unfortunately some of the best big key keyboards are like this. My personal favorite from this category is [MessageEase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb).

A good compromise, with larger keys but familiar "qwerty"-like layout, is the family of keyboards by Ernest Ruckle. I found using the [Qwerty6kb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egruckle.android.qwerty6kb) very nice. The size of the app package is very small and the keyboard is easy to use - the big letters are obtained by tapping on the key and the others on the same key by swiping on the key downwards or upwards. Easy to understand and practical in use.
[image: Qwerty6 version layout, from qwertyxkeyboard.com]